# OData filter ids from a list of strings

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata

I am trying to use Azure Search and OData to filter some IDs in a .net core project.

The IDs are of type `Guid` and the list I am trying to filter is of type `List<string>`.

What I am trying to accomplish is to return all the ids that are included in the `List<string>`

I've tried below, but it doesn't work.

`Filter = SearchFilter.Create($"id contains {ids}")`

Here is my function.

```
public SearchOptions GetSearchOptions(List<string> ids)
{
      var searchOptions = new SearchhOptions()
      {
            Filter = SearchFilter.Create($"id contains {ids}")
      }
      return searchOptions
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter a list of GUID IDs in Azure Search using OData, you can use the in operator to check if the id field is within the list of GUIDs:

```
var searchOptions = new SearchOptions
{
    Filter = string.Join(" or ", ids.Select(id => $"id eq '{id}'"))
};
```